# Fluentd NewRelic output "time must be a Fluent::EventTime (or Integer): Float"

Tags: newrelic, fluentd, td-agent

I'm encountering an issue that I don't understand, extract of config of td-agent:

```
<source>
  @type gelf
  tag gelf-nr
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
  port 12201
</source>

<match gelf-nr**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
  <store>
    @type newrelic
     api_key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  </store>
</match>
```

the output plugin newrelic is always complaining  `gelf failed to emit error="time must be a Fluent::EventTime (or Integer): Float" error_class="ArgumentError`

I tried to edit the field timestamp of the json to nanosecond, but it's not this one which cause the issue.
Extract of the message:

```
2020-09-22 10:00:18.135967969 +0200 gelf-nr: {"version":"1.0","host":"plop-01.stag-21","message":"TEST log plop","level":3,"facility":"plop.log","misc":{"reason":"test erreur","status_code":400,"quote_ids":[1234,5678]},"timestamp":"1600761476000000000","subject"...
```

I'm suspecting that the issue is the initial 2020-09-22 10:00:18.135967969 +0200.
What do you think ? Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of nanoseconds, apparently bug in NR output plugin (outdated implementation) :

```
<source>
...
</source>

<filter **>
  @type record_modifier
  <record>
    timestamp "${timestamp.to_datetime.iso8601(6)}"
  </record>
</filter>

<match **>
...
</match>
```

Comment: Thanks ! my event format seems to be : **2020-09-22 13:39:29.046163082 +0200** what would you use please. Cause I tried but it's the same thing. 
 `time_format %Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%S %z`
 `keep_time_key true` 
 `time_key time`

Comment: Did you try without time_format? Since it parsed timestamp to epoch I assume it can handle it by default

Comment: Do you see time key in resultion stdout?

Comment: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N %z`. I think it's smth else then.

Comment: not better, but thanks.
In stdout yes, I see `2020-09-22 15:25:38.739240884 +0200 <tag>: <json message>`
where tag and json message are of course obfuscated here

Comment: In fact it doesn't change anything to tweak this option, apparently

Comment: Also try removing nanoseconds, e.g. https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch/issues/263#issuecomment-337009627

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221877/discussion-between-mickael-brangeon-and-max-lobur).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working thanks to Max:

I used:

```
<filter **>
@type record_modifier
  <record>
  timestamp "${timestamp.to_datetime.iso8601(6)}"
  </record>
</filter>
```

And removed time parsing (time_Format, keep_time_key). But not time_key as the field in jsons was not time but timestamp.
The issue seems to be in NR not in parser

Comment: woohoo! yeah this is a bug in NR output plugin or even backends. Everything supports nanoseconds these days. Feel free to report to https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-fluentd-output